# How to personalize font in LaTeX (forest)

Tags: fonts, forest

I am drawing a stemma codicum in LaTeX using the package forest. The code works perfectly, but I would need a specific font i.e. Garamond Premier Pro. Is it possible to use it and how? Thanks

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}, 
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
           anchor=north}{}
           },
                            }
            }
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, empty nodes
    [G, l=5]
    [
        [
            [F, tier=1]
            [
                [P, tier=1]
                    [
                        [D, tier=1]
                        [
                            [R, tier=1]
                                [M, tier=1
                                    [m]
                                    [n]
                                ]
                        ]
                    ]
            ]
        ]
        [
            [S, tier=1]
            [L, tier=1]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you own the font, you can use it with either `lualatex` or `xelatex` by using the `fontspec` package.

Comment: And I don't think the font has math support, so you should use a regular text omega instead of `$\Omega$`.